# VS2008 VB BackgroundWorker

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, backgroundworker

I keep reading about using Backgroundworker in VS2008 (VB), but when I attempt to try it I get stuck.

I create a New Project - an ASP.Net Web Application
When I look in the Toolbox for the Backgroundworker object to put onto the form, I find it Grayed-out.

Therefore I cannot go any further.

I want to create an ASP.Net Web Application and use the Backgroundworker object to support getting a ProgressBar working.
And that ProgressBar needs to represent the current Progress of the Backgroundworker DoWork operation.

I'd appreciate any assistance you might be able to provide in getting this off-the-ground.

Thanks

Comment: The `Backgroundworker` control is winforms only. Take a look at this article http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Comment: BackgroundWorker is not a control, and it is not winforms only. But no, it can't work client-side in asp.net page.